# datetimepicker disable time jquery

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I want to use `datetimepicker` to do my reservation function, so I need to disable the time I have been reserved. However, I still can't find a method to work.

I have tried the only similar solution I had seen, but it also failed.
Can anyone kindly help me this problem?

```html
<h3>DateTimePicker</h3>
<input type="text" value="" id="datetimepicker"/><br><br>
```

```js
$.datetimepicker.setLocale('en');

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    lang: 'en',
    disabledDates: ['1986/01/08','1986/01/09','1986/01/10'],
    startDate: '1986/01/05'
});
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({value:'2015/04/15 05:03',step:60});


var specificDates = ['24/12/2014','17/12/2014'];

var hoursToTakeAway = [[14,15],[17]];

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format:'d.m.Y H:i',
    timepicker: true,
    lang: 'en',
    onGenerate: function(ct,$i){
        var ind = specificDates.indexOf(ct.dateFormat('d/m/Y'));
        $('#datetimepicker').show();
        if(ind !== -1) {
            $('#datetimepicker').each(function(index){
                if(hoursToTakeAway[ind].indexOf(parseInt($(this).text())) !== -1)                      
                {
                    $(this).hide();        
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a call to your DB to bring back a collection of booked times.  Then when your datepicker is opened, check each time on the timepicker against times in the DB;  if one matches then grey it out / disable it, else leave it enabled.  Ajax is your friend here.

Comment: thanks for your anwser,but I'm trying to find function to disable time,and I'm stuck..

Answer (score 0):

I kind of resolving my problem by using `onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input)`, I just send the date picked to my controller and return the String array. Then I give that to `allowTimes` to show my time.

```
onChangeDateTime: function(dp,$input){          
    var pick = $input.val();
    $.getJSON('/ShiawaseWeb/Reservation/adjust.controller',{'pick':pick}, function(datas){      
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({allowTimes:datas[0]})
    })
}
```